# Creating a VBA that will find all in text citations and export to another document

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a VBA macro that will identify in-text citations an export them to another page. So far I have had some moderate success but can only get it to work with an expression that finds some citations. I need it to identify all citations both those in parenthesis and out of them. For example
In-text citation

One Author (Smith, 2015) …Smith (2015) argues that….

Two Authors (Smith and Jones, 2015) …according to Smith and Jones
(2015)….

Three Authors (Smith, Jones and Brown,
2015)
….research by Smith, Jones and
Brown (2015) showed that….

Four or more
Authors (Smith et al., 2015) Smith et al. (2015) proved that….

Presently I have this code:

```
Sub ExtractRefsFromSelection()
    MsgBox ("This macro extracts references from selected text.")
    Dim SearchRange As Range, DestinationDoc$, SourceDoc$
    DestinationDoc$ = "Refs.doc"
    SourceDoc$ = ActiveDocument.Name
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs DestinationDoc$, wdFormatDocument
    Documents(SourceDoc$).Activate
    Set SearchRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With SearchRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\([!\)]@[0-9]{4}\)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        While .Execute
            Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.Text = Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.Text + SearchRange.Text
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear, these citations are "plain text", not the result of CITATION fields?

Comment: @jonsson That would indeed be useful to know, since the use of CITSTION fields would make the data extraction a fairly straightforward undertaking - and could even fully express the 'et al' references.

Comment: @macropod Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier and more performant to use the regex library --> add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to your project. Then you can use this code:

```vb
Option Explicit

'this is the complete pattern
Private Const pattern As String = "(\([. \,\w-]+ \d{4}\)|[\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)|[\w-]+ and [\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)|[\w-]+, [\w-]+ and [\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)|[\w-]+ et al. \(\d{4}\))"

'\w only returns characters until ASCII 128 - therefore we have to extend this
Private Const specialCharacters As String = "\A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF\u03B1-\u03C9"  'to replace \w

'just in case - if only single patterns should be searched
'and to understand the single parts
Private Const patternWithinBrackets As String = "\([. \,\w-]+ \d{4}\)"   '(Smith and Jones, 2015)
Private Const patternOneAuthor As String = "[\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)"   'Smith (2015)
Private Const patternTwoAuthors As String = "[\w-]+ and [\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)"  'Smith-Meier and Jones (2015)
Private Const patternThreeAuthors As String = "[\w-]+, [\w-]+ and [\w-]+ \(\d{4}\)"  'Smith, Müller and Brown (2015)
Private Const patternMoreAuthors As String = "[\w-]+ et al. \(\d{4}\)"  'Smith et al. (2015)


Sub printAllCitations()
Dim text As String
text = Selection.text
'text = ThisDocument.Content    'reads the whole document (w/o header/footer etc.)
Debug.Print regEx_Find(text, patternAllCitations)
' Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.Text = regEx_Find(text, patternAllCitations)
End Sub


Public Function regEx_Find(strText As String, pattern As String) As String
'returns a string with all matches concatenated by vbcrlf 

Dim regEx As RegExp: Set regEx = New RegExp
Dim result As String
With regEx
    .pattern = Replace(pattern, "\w", specialCharacters)  'this is the place where we add special characters to the pattern
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    If .Test(strText) = True Then
        Dim matches As MatchCollection
        Dim m As Match
        
        Set matches = .Execute(strText)
        For Each m In matches
            result = result & vbCrLf & m.Value
        Next
    End If
End With
regEx_Find = result
End Function
```