# Word VBA: Modify range based on conditional statement

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a script that extracts parenthetical in-text citations like '(Author, 1992)' from a word doc and copies them to another doc. The code works well to extract all parentheticals, but there are cases where a citation is in the form of "as quoted in Author (1992)..." Where a parenthetical starts with a number, I would like to pull the previous word into the range and copy both over into the new doc. In the above scenario then, we would get 'Author (1992)' rather than just '(1992)' as the code currently operates. I have tried writing a conditional to modify the range using .MoveStart, but it is not capturing the preceding word when the range copies over to the new doc. I know I'm missing some small, significant piece here but can't find any obvious (to me) solutions on other forums questions. Thanks

```
Sub CopyRefs()
  Dim SearchRange As Range, DestinationDoc$, SourceDoc$
  DestinationDoc$ = "Extracted_References.doc"
  SourceDoc$ = ActiveDocument.Name
  Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs DestinationDoc$, wdFormatDocument
  Documents(SourceDoc$).Activate
  Set SearchRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    
  With SearchRange.Find
      Do While .Execute(findText:="\(*\)", _
        MatchWildcards:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindStop, Forward:=True) = True
             
          'this part doesn't seem to work when condition is satisfied 
          If SearchRange.Text Like "\(#*" Then 
              SearchRange.MoveStart wdWord, -1
          End If
          
          'a parenthetical number like (1992) will copy over to new doc but seems_
          'like range not updating to include preceding word in previous step
          Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.InsertAfter SearchRange.Text & vbCr
      Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: look here - this should work for your question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75073995/16578424

Comment: Thanks Ike. I've seen that post and can rewrite using their method, but hoping for some resolution on why .MoveStart does not seem to be functioning in this case. The code works fine otherwise

Comment: Thank you @jonsson. I was looking into documentation for LIKE since I thought that's where the problem was and missed that. The code now works but I am now stuck in an infinite loop when the condition is met (just copies first instance of 'Author (1992)' repeatedly), and will update my code when I figure out how to exit the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jonsson for pointing out the syntax error. Code below functions as intended.

```
Sub CopyRefs()
  Dim SearchRange As Range, DestinationDoc$, SourceDoc$
  DestinationDoc$ = "Extracted_References.doc"
  SourceDoc$ = ActiveDocument.Name
  Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs DestinationDoc$, wdFormatDocument
  Documents(SourceDoc$).Activate
  Set SearchRange = ActiveDocument.Range

  With SearchRange.Find
      Do While .Execute(findText:="\(*\)", _
        MatchWildcards:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindStop, Forward:=True) = True
             
          'Removed backslash since "(" doesn't need to be escaped
          If SearchRange.Text Like "(#*" Then
              SearchRange.MoveStart wdWord, -1
          End If
          
          'copies range to new doc
           Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.InsertAfter SearchRange.Text & vbCr
           
          'collapses range to prevent infinite loop when If condition met
          SearchRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
  End With
End Sub
```